# What is wrong with this query and the subquery?

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this query?
Below is the query and the error I am getting.

> Unknown column 'p.custidd' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.pid ),
               p.parentid,
               p.title,
               p.custid,
               p.totalshares,
               p.totalreplies,
               p.filetype,
               p.filename,
               p.reactions,
               p.sdate,
               c.custid,
               pr.username,
               pr.img,
               pr.signature
FROM   posts_forum AS p,
       profiles_forum AS pr,
       customer_forum AS c,
       posts_to_tags_forum AS p2t,
       customer_tags_forum AS c2t,
       block_forum AS b
WHERE  c.stat = 'y'
       AND c2t.custid = '1'
       AND p2t.pid = p.pid
       AND p2t.tag = c2t.tag
       AND p.custid = c.custid
       AND pr.custid = p.custid
       AND p.custidd NOT IN (SELECT profileid AS custid
                             FROM   block_forum AS b,
                                    posts_forum AS p
                             WHERE  b.custid = '1')
ORDER  BY p.sdate DESC
LIMIT  0, 25
```

Comment: can you please add the output of `desc tablename` for all the tables involved?

Comment: `AND p.custidd NOT IN`...

Comment: I think there is extra `d` in this `AND p.custidd NOT IN `

Comment: Simple typo: FIX THIS: `... AND p.custidd NOT IN (...)`

Comment: `custidd` is presumably a typo for `custid`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot... You see my screen reader is reading both "custid" and "custidd" the same way... Anyway, many many thanks to you. Really sorry for bothering with this little something... Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have typo:

```
AND p.custidd NOT IN (SELECT profileid AS custid
                         FROM   block_forum AS b,
                                posts_forum AS p
                         WHERE  b.custid = '1')
```

where `p.custidd` might be `p.custid`